# The expression "dans l'ordre des choses"

Tags: expressions

> C'est **dans l'ordre des choses**.

As I understand it, the sentence above means "that is only natural". In the following sentence, however, this expression seems to carry a different meaning – which has me puzzled.

> Sache que **dans l'ordre des choses**, il nous est bien plus précieux que toi.

Comment: In English, this would be the order of things, and it would not be: "that is only natural". Also, that is not really the right use of précieux in French. A French person would say: il nous est bien plus cher que toi. You should know that in the order of things, he is more precious to us than you. être cher à quelqu'un. Il m'est cher: He is precious to me.

Comment: @Lambie: Nothing wrong with *précieux* ([I. 2. b](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9cieux)). It has a slightly different meaning than *cher*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48500/discussion-between-stephane-gimenez-and-lambie).

Comment: @LUNA: It seems that second sentence comes from the subtitles of a movie with least English, French, Dutch and Polish variants. Did it simply come across while looking for the meaning of this French expression on reverso? Do you maybe know what movie they come from?

Comment: Apparently it's from [The Puppet Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters_(film)), originally in English. “All you need to know is that in the scheme of things, she is much more valuable to us than you are.”

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. A French speaker working in my office used the first sentence in conversation. So I went on to look for more example sentences with this expression, trying to get a solid grasp on its usage. Then I came across the second example sentence in a dictionary or something. Obviously, the definition that applies to the first sentence does not to the second. So I posted this question. By the way, I'm in the dark just as much as you are about where the second sentence originally comes from.

Comment: Yep, I knew there was something off about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, in the first sentence “l'ordre des choses” expresses a natural consequence. “Ordre” has temporal and causative implications. Wiktionary provides the following definition:

> Ce qui arrive, ce qui se passe, sans qu’il soit possible de le discuter, de le refuser.

Quite surprisingly, in the second sentence it's used with a much more literal meaning. If all things were ranked according to how precious they are to us, he would come before you (by far). “Ordre” is to be understood as a comparison order, but using “ordre des choses” for a universal, absolute scale of importance in this way sounds very unusual<sup>1</sup> and quite literary.

–
<sup>1. Apparently it was chosen for lack of a better translation that fits the format of subtitles.</sup>

Comment: Do you think  that "in the (grand) scheme of things = putting things into perspective" is a good translation for "dans l'ordre des choses" in the second example?

Comment: “Ordre” may have a meaning similar to “scheme” or “arrangement”, “organization”. And this is a more accurate description of my own understanding than the comparison order I mentioned previously. What the translation team came up with is rather ok but unusual. The use of “ordre des choses” is really confusing here because it's a normally a dedicated idiomatic expression that implies causality, which it cannot be in this sentence.

Comment: So we are discussing translation from English into French from a sentence that comes from a badly translated movie script? The French has at least three mistakes in it.

Answer (score 1):

#### meaning

[expressions-françaises](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-c/2696-c-est-dans-l-ordre-des-choses.html) :

> Le dictionnaire des expressions et locutions définit l’expression française *c’est dans l’ordre des choses* comme **un événement normal, inévitable et prévisible**.

[wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/c%27est%20dans%20l%27ordre%20des%20choses) :

> that's the way it goes, that's the order of things, nothing to be done about it

---

#### Particular sentence

> > Sachez que dans l'ordre des choses, il nous est bien plus précieux que toi.

In your particular sentence, the verb *savoir* indicates the speaker is reminding the context, the natural, bounded to happen, order of things. In this context, *"il"* is more valuable than the listener.